# Datos no llegan al php a través de AJAX con jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Tengo el siguiente código

**JS**

```
$('#form').on('submit', (function (e) {
    var contenido = ed.getData();
    var title = $("#tituloArt").val();
    var cat = $("#categoria").val();
    alert(contenido+" // "+title+" // "+cat);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "publicar.php",
        data: {
            content: contenido,
            titulo: title,
            categoria: cat,
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            //location.href = "../inicio/";
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error al procesar los datos");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

**PHP**

```
echo $_POST['tituloArt']." // ".$_POST['content']."//".$_POST['categoria'];
```

El alert de la línea 5 del código JS me muestra los datos correctamente, pero el alert del "success" de la linea 17 me muestra warnings de que las variables $_POST['...'] no están definidas. ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

[image: Captura del apartado de "Network"]

**Edit 1**

Se me olvidó añadir que la variable contenido puede tener carácteres html como "<". No sé si tendrá algo que ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta bien lo que has echo solo que al recibir los datos estas pidiendo "tituloArt" y lo que envías es "titulo". Intenta con esto:

```
echo $_POST['titulo']." // ".$_POST['content']."//".$_POST['categoria'];
```